# Writing Datetime to excel with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to export my Data table to excel. It consist of 16 columns where 2 are date time.

I was able to convert datetime to date and save the file without getting this error message:
***ValueError: time data '2023-04-07 13:06:18.931000+00:00' does not match format 'DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS' (match).***
If I change the format to DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS then that error appears:
**ValueError: Excel does not support datetimes with timezones. Please ensure that datetimes are timezone unaware before writing to Excel.**

```
    df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicts)#assign the data to pandas

    #change datetime to excel format. Excel don't have datetime
    df2['Creation date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Creation date'],format="DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS",utc=True)
    df2['Updated date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Updated date'],format="DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS",utc=True)
```

How can I convert it and keep to desired format and avoid timezone error?

Comment: AFAIK `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` is not an "Excel Format". Why do you think that is the way to solve this problem?

Comment: ehhh, wrong code. I've pasted the old one. Sorry. I fixed it but then run into match error.

Comment: When you convert to datetime, the format tells you the expected format of the data you are reading (and converting) - that is the data in the 'Creation date' column in your dataframe. It has nothing to do with the resulting datetime value. Your dates in the column are not in the right format for conversion to datetime when you run this code: `df2['Creation date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Creation date'],format="DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS",utc=True)`

Comment: Note: if you are looking for help converting dates you should at least provide some sample of the data (and, since this is pandas and dates, what is the datatype of the dataframe column containing the dates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok decided to conver it into str and avoid any problems with date and time zones etc.

```
    df2['Creation date'] = df2['Creation date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df2['Updated date'] = df2['Updated date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```